# Were all the sons of Zeus brothers of all the godly sons and daughters of Zeus?

Tags: greek, demi-gods

Since in Greek mythology, there are sons of Zeus as demigods, are they brothers of all the godly sons and daughters of Zeus?

Also, wouldn't the demigod's mother technically be the mother in law of Zeus' offspring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Demigods and the Godly offspring of Zeus would be half-siblings.

The title step-mother comes by marriage, at the very least in the common law sense, however most of Zeus's special lady friends were mistresses or one night stands.

This is all without going in to some of the more curious reproductive methods.

Comment: In ancient Greek society, which Olympus largely models, a distinction was made between half-siblings through the father and half-siblings through the mother: they had a differing legal statuses  The former were allowed to intermarry, for instance;  that latter were not allowed.  typical than that between Herakles and Hera (Herakles was bound to his stepmother for exceptional reasons).

Comment: Step-mothers had little or no binding authority over step-children, but that's not unexpected since mothers had little legal authority over their biological children.  The relationship between Hippolytus and Phaedra, for example, was more

Answer (score 0):

In ancient Greek society, which Olympus largely models, a distinction was made between half-siblings through the father and half-siblings through the mother: they had a differing legal statuses  The former were allowed to intermarry, for instance;  that latter were not allowed.  Step-mothers had little or no binding authority over step-children, but that's not unexpected since mothers had little legal authority over their biological children.  The relationship between Hippolytus and Phaedra, for example, was more typical than that between Herakles and Hera (Herakles was bound to his stepmother for exceptional reasons).